# Linking local installation of GLFW

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, glfw, premake

I want to link against a project installed, rather than OS installed, version of GLFW to make my project more portable. I am trying to use both premake and gcc directly but they both fail.

The glfw directory is in `project/libraries/glfw-3.2.1`

I tried to build glfw by doing:

```
cd project/libraries/glfw-3.2.1
mkdir bin
cd bin
cmake ..
make all
```

however I do not see any binary on that directory although I did find the file `libglfw3.a`

So I tried to build it manually as follows:

```
g++ main.cpp -I libraries/glfw-3.2.1/include/ -L libraries/glfw-3.2.1/bin/src/libglfw3.a
```

However that fails to link as none of the glfw objects are found. i.e
I get errors like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
g++ main.cpp -I libraries/glfw-3.2.1/include -L libraries/glfw-3.2.1/bin/src -lglfw3
```

Using `-L` you are telling the compiler where the library lies but you should use -l to link it

Comment: Almost correct, it seems it should be glfw and not glfw3 for the -l, thanks a lot